# Rogue files in my RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the root of my rails 3.2 application out of some reason occasionally empty files are being created. The have the file names "Integer,", "0" or "1" or "-1".

I remember also having seen them being postfixed with semicolons, but am unsure about this.

I wonder what could trigger this? Anyone did experience something similar, so I could get a pointer where and how to look?

To me it seems a bit as if a boolean comparison was piped into IO or something like that...

Thanks!

Comment: With absolutely nothing to go off of as to possible causes, do you have your code tracked in a vcs like git? If so, you can checkout your code at various points in history to narrow down where the change was introduced.

Comment: I think this behavior is as old as the app itself. My hope was that this was a known symptom of a certain illness. I am under the impression that a gem could be the cause of this.